# How can I create date-time stamp directories and save OpenCV-made files into the created folders?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am working with OpenCV-Python, and I want to save captured pictures into DateTime stamp folders. Each file was created with incremental numbers, so I want to create date-time stamp folders then save created files in it. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Some code examples would be fine, so we can see what exactly might be wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for getting the date last modified is mentioned here

[How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

One thing to be mid-full of is that you format the datetime without any forbidden chars for the platform you are using.

You may also want to have a list of files, create a set of directories and create them upfront, rather than doing creating them while iterating over the files.

Comment: I have found the answer at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923453/create-dir-with-datetime-name-and-subfiles-within-directory-python/55942714#55942714